# No Payment method available after upgrade to magento 2.1.13

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, magento-upgrade

I have magento 2.1 store first installation from theme bought.

The folder structure like below:

```
app/code/Magento
```

I upgraded to 2.1.13 using composer and moved magento core files to vendor.

I did all regular command lines like

```
setup:upgrade

setup:di:compile

setup:static-content:deploy

cache:flush/clean
```

The store works fine but accidentally in checkout page

```
  Payment Information

  No Payment method available.
```

No errors in debug log and I changed the them to luma

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed "heard4us" module in your Magento Store?

Heard it creates problems in checkout process for many. It is not compatible. I am sure you will fix it by removing this module.

Comment: No I do not install

Comment: I have heard that module creating problems. You must not be having any issue. Are you sure that you're using the latest update?